# Flutter windows: Is there any way I can get currently focused apps name on flutter app (windows/macOS)

Tags: flutter, windows, macos, dart

I am trying to build an tracker app for windows and macOS on flutter. It's kind of employee management system e.g. Workfolio. Is there any way I can get the name of the app or site (if I'm on browser) I'm currently on. Is there any package or any alternative way to do that.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I just asked is there any package or other way by which I can get the application name I'm currently using on my pc. It's will be a tracking app. As I've no idea whether there is any way I can do that using flutter. Thats why I haven't written any code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the issue. This will show Currently active window name.

```
import 'dart:ffi' as ffi;
import 'package:ffi/ffi.dart';
import 'package:win32/win32.dart' as win;

String name = '';
void getActiveWinName(){
    int hwnd = win.GetForegroundWindow();
    ffi.Pointer<Utf16>? namePtr = name.toNativeUtf16();
    int? y = win.GetWindowTextLength(hwnd);
    win.GetWindowText(hwnd, namePtr, y+1);
    name = namePtr.toDartString(length: y);
    print(name);
    win.free(namePtr);
}
```

Comment: Hi Sharif, your answer looks like it only work on Windows OS since you're depending on the win32 plugin. Found a way to get the currently active windows for other platforms like Linux and Mac yet? Thanks.